# Formatar campo de data para exibir na página EJS com Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js, ejs

Estou usando Node.JS para recuperar os dados de uma tabela de MySQL, porém eu gostaria que o  campo de data fosse exibido na view EJS com o formato "DD/MM/YYYY". Está sendo exibido "Thu Jul 15 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)"

```
const Pedido = connection.define('pedido',{ 
   numero:{
       type: Sequelize.STRING(10),
       allowNull: true
   },
   dataemissao:{
       type: Sequelize.DATE,
       allowNull: true
   }
...
```

A view EJS está assim;

```
<% pedidos.forEach(pedido=>{%>                                                          
    <td><%=pedido.cliente.nome%></td>
    <td><%=pedido.dataemissao%></td>
<%});%>
```